# Is it possible to hide the scrollbar in Terminal?

Tags: terminal

In the 10.4 or maybe 10.5 versions of Terminal.app it was possible to hide the scrollbar completely. Does anyone know if this is still possible in the 10.6 version of Terminal.app?

Comment: Dupe: http://superuser.com/questions/178424/snow-leopard-hide-scrollbar-in-terminal

Answer (score 2):

As of OS X Lion 10.7 scrollbars can be hidden system-wide, including in Terminal, with

> System Preferences > General > Show scroll bars

If you have a “touch” input device, like a trackpad or Magic Mouse, they are hidden by default.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the Terminal application from a previous version of the Mac OS X, or (if you are able) alter the file containing the user interface definition (the file ending in .nib or .xib).

Answer (score 0):

There is not an easy way to remove the scrollbar from Terminal.app in 10.6. Your best option is to download [iTerm](http://iterm.sourceforge.net/) which allows you to remove the scrollbar, and also gives you a bunch of other options that Terminal.app does not have.

Answer (score 0):

Try [LionScrollbars](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/41429/lionscrollbars). It's the only thing that worked for me. Works like a charm under 10.8.2.